# random quiz with radio buttons javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do the following. When a user visits my page I want to have a prompt asking the user how many questions they want to take (from 1 till 10). If the user enters e.g 5 then 5 randomly selected questions should be displayed (out of 10 possible). Also, there must be no duplicates. I would like to inform you that I am not experienced in javascript at all. I have done something but I need your help about the arrays. I have put a comment where I need help. I am also open for other ways on how to do that.

Thanks

html code with 3 questions radio buttons as an example

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<title> Submitting information </title> </head>
<body>


 <form id="quiz">
 <br/>

 What's the capital of Bulgaria?

 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="q1" id="city1" value="Sofia"/>
               <label for="city1">Sofia</label> 

    <br>

 <input type="radio" name="q1" id="city2" value="Buchurest" />
               <label for="city2">Buchurest</label> <br>

 <input type="radio" name="q1" id="city3" value="Skopie" />
               <label for="city3">Skopie</label>

  <br> <br> <br>

     What's the capital of Mexico?

 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="q2" id="cit1" value="Mexico city"/>
               <label for="cit1">Mexico city</label>

    <br>

 <input type="radio" name="q2" id="cit2" value="Karakaz" />
               <label for="cit2">Karakaz</label> <br>

 <input type="radio" name="q2" id="cit3" value="Lisbon" />
               <label for="cit3">Lisbon</label>

       <br> <br> <br>
             Who's the current UK prime minister?

   <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" id="qq1" value="David Cameron"/>
               <label for="qq1">David Cameron</label>

    <br>

  <input type="radio" name="q3" id="qq2" value="Lloyd George" />
               <label for="qq2">Lloyd George</label> <br>

  <input type="radio" name="q3" id="qq3" value="Gordon Brown" />
               <label for="qq3">Gordon Brown</label>



  </p>
  </form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is a tricky part. That's my javascript code:

```
 function randomInt(low, high) 
 // Given   : low <= high 
 // Returns : a random integer in the range [low, high] 
 { 
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(high-low+1)) + low; 
 }          

        function randomOneOf(list) 
   // Given  : list is a nonempty list (array) 
   // Returns: a random item from the list 
    {    
     return list[randomInt(0, list.length-1)]; 
      }

    var global = prompt("Select No of questions which you want to be               
     displayed")

    // function to document.write specific No of random questions from a set of   
      questions  (between 1 and 10). 
    // For example user may prompt 5 random questions to be displayed out of 10 
    function result()
    {
        // create an array to store the quiz questions
        var arr = new Array();
        arr[0] = ??               //how to store the quiz questions??. 
      Maybe form('quiz').q1 or ??. Thanks
        arr[1] = ??
        arr[2] = ??
        .. // till 10

        // create another array to store the random number questions that 
      should appear
        var newarr = new Array();

        // finding the first random no.
        var s = function randomOneOf(arr)

        // add the first number to the new array of random numbers
        newarr.push(s);
        n = 1;

        // add the rest of the questions to the array depending on global 
     var (how many numbers of questions the user wants)
        while (n <= global)
            {
                // find the 2nd random Number
                n = function randomOneOf(arr)
                for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++)
                   {
    // not allowing duplicates within the random numbers
                        if n.value != newarr[i]
                           {
                                newarr.push(n) 
                                n++
                            }

                   }                       

            }

            // displaying the random questions 
                for (var k = 0; k < newarr.length; k++)
                    {
                        for j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)

                            if (newarr[k] == arr[j])
                            {

                    document.write(newarr[k]);
                            }

                    }   
     }
```

Comment: hard to read through this....suggest you start by creating an array of unique random numbers that will be used as the indexes for questions.  Zero to available questions length less one. Then loop that index array to create array of questions to output. Once you have the random number array...second step is fairly easy and will help you focus on 2 individual steps. Get first step figured out before second

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replay. However, my point is that I cannot put the quiz questions to an array as I don't know how to do that (they are based on radio buttons).

And also, I don't think it's so hard to read through. I've put comments on all lines.

Comment: OK...so you need help creating a data format for questions? As well as how to output them. Can they all be in page html right from the start( hidden of course until needed)? If so that would make it really easy to just remove unneeded ones

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<b>Please enter the number of questions you would like to answer:</b> <input id='numQ' type='text'/>

<script>
    var quiz = {
        "questions": ["question1", ..., "question10"],
        "answers": [
            {"answers": ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"], "correct": 1}, 
            ..., 
            {"answers": ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"], "correct": 3}
        ]
    };

    //You may want to error check here for correct type (int) and non-null value
    var numQ = document.getElementById('numQ').value; 

    var questionsAsked = [];
    while (numQ >= 1) { //Not counting down to 0 because numQ is an inclusive value
        //Generate random number r from [0-9]
        if(questionsAsked.indexOf(r) > -1) {
            //this question has been used before, do nothing
        } else { //This question hasn't been used yet
            //Write to the page however you want quiz.questions[r]
            questionsAsked.push(r);
            --numQ;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please write it down for me. Just for an example. I don't get how should I do it exactly. I don't get the role of questionsAsked.

Comment: What do you want written down? I pretty much wrote the whole thing - could you be more specific?

The purpose of questionsAsked is to make sure you don't repeat questions. It keeps track of the indices of which questions we have asked, making sure then that those questions are never chosen again.

Comment: I've edited the example a little to make the check more clear.